# System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'eventDate'

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

When this query used in sql it works fine but when trying to use it in c# it says: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'eventDate'. What does this error mean?

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DATEPART(yyyy, eventDate)  FROM events group by eventDate", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        ddlLocation.DataSource = dt;
        ddlLocation.DataTextField = "eventDate";
        ddlLocation.DataValueField = "eventDate";
        ddlLocation.DataBind();
        ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", ""));
```

Gridview

```
 protected void BindGridview()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString());
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id, eventDate, eventName from events ", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    gvDetails.DataSource = dt;
    gvDetails.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: which line in these codes throw?

Comment: You are selecting the eventDate as OrderYear. Instead of binding to eventDate, bind to OrderYear

Comment: sorry, was mistake... i just remove as orderDate.

Comment: this line  ddlLocation.DataBind();

Answer (score 4):

try the same code but with this query it might work

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DATEPART(yyyy, eventDate) AS eventDate FROM events group by eventDate", con);
```

change the alias name of your select query :)

Comment: this code bind year correctly in dropdownlist but it throw this error : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.